# JComponent unwantedly grabs focus whenever alt key is pressed

Tags: java, swing, focus

I am trying to build a simple text editor. On the left side there is supposed to be the text field for input and on there right side I am trying to setup a pdf viewer. Those individually work fine, but when I put them together the pdf viewer always grabs focus whenever i press the "alt" key, which prevents me from entering certain characters in the text field.

The PDF-Viewer I am using is based on the "Swing-Native" project (http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/). It works by simulating a window for programs to run in, inside of a JComponent. This works fine, but whenever I press the alt key the pdf-viewer grabs focus for menu-short cuts. It does this independently of what component currently is in focus.

I tried quite some things to fix it, including setting the viewer's setFocusable Method to false and using Focus- and Key-Listeners in combination with the requestFocus/requestWindowFocus methods of my text area to request focus for the text area whenever the "alt" key is pressed. None of things I have tried resulted in any change of behavior what so ever.

The PDF-Viewer implements a class called JWebBrower from the "Swing-Native" project, which in itself is a JPanel. During initialization the following values are set:

```
setStatusBarVisible(false);
setBarsVisible(false);
setActionMap(null);
setAutoscrolls(false);
setFocusable(false);
```

This should normally make the JPanel non focusable, except it doesn't. In a simple KeyListener which is registered to the TextArea I tried to fix the problem with resetting the focus from the display object (the pdf-viewer) to the text area.

```
        text.requestFocusInWindow();
        display.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        display.setFocusable(false);
```

This also did prove itself to be quite useless. The interesting thing is, that the KeyListener gets triggered, but the JTextArea does not register the keystrokes. I thought about dispatching a DocumentEvent to the text area, but I don't really know how to do it correctly and surely there must be a better way to fix the problem than that.

Interesting enough the caret also changes whenever the "alt" key is pressed, indicating that the viewer component took over. The caret changes back to normal, once i click on the TextArea, but that only lasts as long as the "alt" key remains untouched.

Any ideas are welcome, I am absolutely clueless as of right now.

EDIT: upon further inspection I found out, that KeyBindings for every Key masked with the alt key also don't work on the TextArea. I was also unable to figure out how the keys are bound to the troubling component as both input and action maps for it are empty and it does not appear to have any listeners bound to it.

EDIT2: I found a work around: After some digging in the source code I found out that the component that causes trouble overrides the `processKeyEvent` Method of the Component.class. It sends it to a custom ComponentPeer which consumes the event and grabs focus. My solution is to rip out the entire ComponentPeer by the root using reflection.

```
// Capturing peer to get rid of annoying key events
Component nativeComp = getNativeComponent();
try {
    Field peer = Component.class.getDeclaredField("peer");
    peer.setAccessible(true);
    ComponentPeer peer1 = (ComponentPeer) peer.get(nativeComp);

    if (peer1 != null) {
        SlavePeer newPeer = new SlavePeer(peer1);
        peer.set(nativeComp, newPeer);
    }
} catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but it works. The `SlavePeer` Class extends ComponentPeer and just redirects everything except certain KeyEvents to the original peer.

Comment: You've mentioned all the things you've tried but have left out what may likely be the most important -- key bindings. Have you determined what key causes the problem (just the alt key?), and if so, how it is bound to the troublesome component?

Comment: Try adding a Key Binding to the text field to handle the Alt key. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339708/disable-single-alt-type-to-activate-the-menu for a possible solution.

Comment: It is any key masked with the alt key. Keybindings also don't get called for those.

Comment: 1) Tip: Add @HovercraftFullOfEels (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).